# Apache Camel Integration Test - NotifyBuilder

Tags: esb, apache-camel

I am writing integration tests to test existing Routes. The recommended way of getting the response looks something like this (via [Camel In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182366) section 6.4.1):

```
public class TestGetClaim extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Produce(uri = "seda:getClaimListStart")
    protected ProducerTemplate producer;

    @Test
    public void testNormalClient() {
        NotifyBuilder notify = new NotifyBuilder(context).whenDone(1).create();

        producer.sendBody(new ClientRequestBean("TESTCLIENT", "Y", "A"));
        boolean matches = notify.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertTrue(matches);

        BrowsableEndpoint be = context.getEndpoint("seda:getClaimListResponse", BrowsableEndpoint.class);
        List<Exchange> list = be.getExchanges();
        assertEquals(1, list.size());
        System.out.println("***RESPONSE is type "+list.get(0).getIn().getBody().getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

The test runs but I get nothing back. The `assertTrue(matches)` fails after the 5 second timeout.

If I rewrite the test to look like this I get a response:

```
@Test
public void testNormalClient() {
    producer.sendBody(new ClientRequestBean("TESTCLIENT", "Y", "A"));
    Object resp = context.createConsumerTemplate().receiveBody("seda:getClaimListResponse");
    System.out.println("***RESPONSE is type "+resp.getClass().getName());
}
```

The documentation is a little light around this so can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with the first approach? Is there anything wrong with following the second approach instead?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I have broken this down and it looks like the problem is with the mix of **seda** as the start endpoint in combination with the use of a **recipientList** in the Route. I've also changed the construction of the NotifyBuilder (I had the wrong endpoint specified).

- If I change the start endpoint to
  **direct** instead of **seda** then the test will work; or
- If I comment out the **recipientList**
  then the test will work.

Here's a stripped down version of my Route that reproduces this issue:

```
public class TestRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
//      from("direct:start")    //works
        from("seda:start")  //doesn't work
        .recipientList(simple("exec:GetClaimList.bat?useStderrOnEmptyStdout=true&args=${body.client}"))
        .to("seda:finish");
    }

}
```

Note that if I change the source code of the **NotifyTest** from the "*Camel In Action*" source to have a route builder like this then it also fails.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use "seda:getClaimListResponse" in the getEndpoint to be sure the endpoint uri is 100% correct

Comment: Thanks Claus. I've updated the question. The GetClaimListRouteBuilder.responseNode is just a static method that returns the same string. I've replaced it and re-run the test with the same results.

Comment: Claus, I have identified some issues and updated my question. Does the outcome seem strange to you?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: It appears that notifyBuilder in conjunction with seda queues are not quite working: a test class to illustrate:

```
public class NotifyBuilderTest extends CamelTestSupport {

// Try these out!
// String inputURI = "seda:foo";   // Fails
// String inputURI = "direct:foo"; // Passes

@Test
public void testNotifyBuilder() {

    NotifyBuilder b = new NotifyBuilder(context).from(inputURI)
            .whenExactlyCompleted(1).create();

    assertFalse( b.matches() );
    template.sendBody(inputURI, "Test");
    assertTrue( b.matches() );

    b.reset();

    assertFalse( b.matches() );
    template.sendBody(inputURI, "Test2");
    assertTrue( b.matches() );
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from(inputURI).to("mock:foo");
        }
    };
}
}
```